# Jquery Number Roller

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Does anyone know a way or a tutorial on how to make a number roller?

What I want to do is supply a function with a starting number, increment rate and ending number. It would then start at the starting number and finish at the ending number.

But, for the first few seconds of increase or decrease, the rate accelerates and then decelerates as it reaches the end number. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Does the -1 mean you don't know too? I have to guess why you did that as you haven't backed it up with a comment...

Comment: My guess would be because its a poorly written question, that shows no attempt of solving the issue before asking for help. At least show some examples of how you would like the code to work, what you have tried and so forth. But I believe what you are looking for is something similar to [animation easing](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), so have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this plugin:
http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example/?style=light

What you have to do? Display a number, show new one, and change position for old number and hide it (all with jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)). Thats one of iteration of your loop, repeat until you reach chosen number.

What about increasing/decreasing speed? Animate contains duration property, just change it at the end and the beggining of your loop:

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfIterations; ++i) {
    if(i<=(numberOfIterations/10) || i>=(numberOfIterations/10))
        duration = 1000;
    else
        duration = 100;
}
```